# Multipole expansion of Woods-Saxon potential?

Tags: electrostatics, nuclear-physics, multipole-expansion

When can a distribution be expanded in multipoles? What is the basic requirement?

Can it be done for a potential like the [Woods-Saxon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woods%E2%80%93Saxon_potential) form?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion) is pretty clear about what kinds of functions a multipole expansion works for, I'd say.

Comment: Note, every part of a multipole expansion is a harmonic function, so the sum is a harmonic function.

Comment: A multipole expansion is used for the angular components of a distribution. The Woods-Saxon potential is generally given as a function of the radial variable, so after a separation of variables, the multipole expansion is no different than what one would obtain for any other spherically-symmetric potential, like a harmonic oscillator or Coulomb potential. The difference is in the radial distribution.